# How to justified with overflow

Tags: javascript, css

I have these two elements. The inner one is set to 100% width. This makes it fill the outer element.

I want to adjust the inner element's left position. This makes it move the right as well.

The problem is hard to explain, but I have the inner box scrolling to the left as the outer one is `overflow: hidden`.

Even with the left being changed I'd like to have the inner element's right side be justified to the outer element's right side.

I also need to get it so the right side can overflow which it does because there are smaller elements inside the inner element that have a `min-width` forcing it to be a minimum size if the left value is increased.

But this poses a conflict between the position when the overflow is on the left creating space on the outside right of the inner element. This is compounded because the `.outer` element is changing size on window resize which I do want the outer element to resize like that.

This is my css:

```
.outer{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    background-color: red;
    border: 0;
}

.inner{
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    transition: left 0.5s;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I have javascript changing the left value on `.inner`. The problem appears mostly on window resize as the left value is changed to keep one of inner's children in view.

The objective is to create a scroll effect on `.inner` during a window resize, or while a button is clicked. I can click a button to make it scroll, but this window resizing is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `right:0` on an absolute (or relative, fixed) positioned element:

```
.outer{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    background-color: red;
    border: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.inner{
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    left: 0; /* or any other value you like */
    right: 0;
    transition: left 0.5s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't use absolute, but  `right 0;` did work with relative. Funny. I thought I had already tried that. You might want to update your answer to reflect that it also works with relative while using flex box on the inner element. Since part of the answer did help me figure out the problem yours is the accepted answer.